# unable to use ctrl f to go back to a suspended program in vim

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to ubuntu and vim. I was writing a 'C' language code in vim. After saving the file , I used ctrl + z to suspend the program but I am unable to go back to the source code by pressing ctrl+f. Please help me with this.

Comment: Oh yes, I feel so stupid to have asked the question now . Thanks for the help. I almost spent half an hour trying to find a solution.

Comment: Isn't the command supposed to be `fg` (not `CTRL-F`)?? Maybe you're used to having it aliased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash (the default shell in Ubuntu, though the following applies to most other shells, too), the suspended programs can be listed with the `jobs` command, and `fg` (optionally followed by a `[jobspec]`) puts it back to the `f`ore`g`round.

Next time you're struggling with something like this, bring up the corresponding *man page*:

```
$ man bash
```

A quick search for "suspend" brings you right to the chapter *job control*!